# CSS not being applied to HTML page in Flask

Tags: python, css, flask, web-applications

I am implementing a flask based webpage and my CSS is failing to load. When I start the flask program and access the test page, I can see the HTML content, but the CSS fails to load at all,and  shows a 404 error in the command line.
I am using the recommended file structure for holding static webpages, and I am holding all of my CSS files in the static folder. My HTML templates work, and I'm accessing them in the same way. My flask code is included below as well.

[image]

```
import os
import logging

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_caching import Cache


# Change the format of messages logged to Stackdriver
logging.basicConfig(format="%(message)s", level=logging.INFO)

config = {
    "DEBUG": True,  # some Flask specific configs
    "CACHE_TYPE": "SimpleCache",  # Flask-Caching related configs
    "CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT": 300,
}


TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.abspath(
    "D:/User/Documents/GitHub/CSC 172/Dandyhacks2021/Flask/templates"
)
STATIC_DIR = os.path.abspath(
    "D:/User/Documents/GitHub/CSC 172/Dandyhacks2021/Flask/static"
)

print(STATIC_DIR)

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=TEMPLATE_DIR, static_folder=STATIC_DIR)
app.config.from_mapping(config)
cache = Cache(app)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route("/homepage")
def homepage():
    return "Homepage placeholder or some shit"


@app.route("/cache")
@cache.cached(timeout=50)
def cachedpage():
    return "Cached for 50 seconds"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

Here's the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Léelo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Flask/static/homepagestyle.css">
</head>
<img id="logo" src="Flask/images/Léelo.png" alt="Léelo"><br>
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html" target="blank">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="libros.html" target="blank">LIBROS</a></li>
        <li><a href="..." target="blank">LITERATURA</a></li>
        <li><a href="..." target="blank">MARKET PLACE</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p></p>

<body div style="background-image: url(images/background.png);">
    <div class="container">

        <section class="lead">
            <h1>QUIÉNES SOMOS?</h1>
            <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum.</strong> El libro empieza con nuestro narrador contando que cuando tenia solo 6
                años, por algo que leyó en un libro, dibujó una boa comiéndose un elegante. Orgulloso de su dibujo,
                decide enseñárselo a las personas mayores, pero éstas piensan que es un sombrero. Al no entender su
                dibujó, ellos le dicen que deje de dibujar y mejor se dedique a las matemáticas o la gramática.
                Desilusionado, sigue su consejo.</p><br>
            <h1>CUÁL ES NUESTRA META?</h1>
            <p>El libro empieza con nuestro narrador contando que cuando tenia solo 6 años, por algo que leyó en un
                libro, dibujó una boa comiéndose un elegante. Orgulloso de su dibujo, decide enseñárselo a las personas
                mayores, pero éstas piensan que es un sombrero. Al no entender su dibujó, ellos le dicen que deje de
                dibujar y mejor se dedique a las matemáticas o la gramática. Desilusionado, sigue su consejo. </p>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p>Made by: Team Goat</p><br>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: With no HTML to look at my best suggestion is to make sure there are no typos when calling the style sheet.

Comment: I'll add the HTML if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing Flask from /Flask/static/homepagestyle.css
so it looks like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/homepagestyle.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use relative paths for now. When in production, use the static paths.

Also, make sure you are requesting the correct urls from the static files itself.